# Software or managed service for AWS Lambda job scheduling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a relatively large number of tasks that need to be executed at certain intervals, hourly, daily, weekly etc. These tasks are easily defined as AWS Lambda functions and I can schedule them easily enough with AWS Eventbridge.

However, in many cases jobs can fail due to delayed or missing data or other micro services going down. Take, for example, a function that is configured to run every hour and process data from hour X to hour X+1 and serialize to some data store (the ETL use case). Suppose at 1am some service becomes unavailable and the job fails until engineering is able to address the issue at 10am, at which point the code for the lambda is updated.

The desired behavior would be for that job to pick up where it left off and quickly catch up and process data from 1am to 10am (sequentially).

It would be relatively straightforward to implement some state-tracking service manually, where interval success/fails are tracked and can be checked and registered via simple API calls. My question is whether there is existing software for this sort of application/service, as far as I can tell Apache Airflow can do this but it also comes with significantly more complexity and overhead than is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

1. Track state of your application with [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions). You can implement coordination between Lambda functions, add [parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html) or sequential processing etc. Step Functions also support error handling and have built-in retry mechanisms.
2. Depending on the volume and velocity of data you ingest, you could go with [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) or [Amazon Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) to stream the data to Lambda functions. With SQS, you could use [retry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/sqs-retries.html) for every message. If the message couldn't be processed, you can put it into [Dead-Letter Queue (DLQ)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) for further investigation. Also, this approach is highly scalable and allows parallel execution of jobs.

Comment: From what I can tell the retry mechanism is pretty limited for AWS step functions, it has a max of 6 hours. In the example I have above that 6hr would be hit, but also there may be a code change needed to update the Lambda. There is no functionality AFAIK to restart where it left off.

Comment: This blog post should help. To achieve the resume mechanism you need to save your state somewhere. SQS could be a good option.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/improved-failure-recovery-for-amazon-eventbridge/